# How to solve liker error:can't link directly with lib system_configuration.dylib

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics-sdk

I am adding Google Analytics a bit older version by directly downloading the libraries for a reason. 
Followed this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios

but after adding all the files and trying to build basic analytics code I am stuck at a linker error

> ld: cannot link directly with /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib.  Link against the umbrella framework 'System.framework' instead. for architecture x86_64

I am not sure what exactly is happening , my Xcode is at 7.2 and trying to run this code on iPhone 6 simulator.

****  EDIT ***
Also above error has occurred after adding Google Analytics specific libs and headers

---

Comment: Why not use a dependency management tool (cocoapods) or git submodules? It seems that an old tutorial could be error prone.